# Json objects to CSV file c#

Tags: c#, json, csv

I want to write my JSON objects into a csv file in c#
I'm using a web api from a windows 8.1 client, I tried this tutorial but "DeserializeXmlNode" seems to be missing, and XmlNode too!
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/565920/Create-CSV-from-JSON-in-Csharp

here's the code i use to get the api response:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)          
{
        var server = "http://localhost:1504/api";
        var service = System.IO.Path.Combine(server, "PlayerStats");
        var playerstat = await GetAsync<IEnumerable<Common.Models.PlayerStat>>(new Uri(service));  

    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var http = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var response = await http.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.StatusCode != Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode.Ok)
            {
                throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using System.XML and Newtonsoft.Json but why do I keem missing references, and is there a way to write my objects directy to a csv?

Comment: What does xml have to do with converting json to csv?

Comment: It's in the link, the guy used XmlNodeReader, he converted the json object to xml then to csv. I want to have csv but it's the only thing i found so far. 
I was trying a dump way using "foreach" to access evry object in my IEnumerable and write it's values separated by "," but the things is i can only access to a value by using "o.AttribueX", what if in my query i didnt select AttributeX? I'll be trying to write something that doesn't exist! Any better way to convert this?

Comment: You need the namespace [`System.Xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a reference to `System.Xml.dll`

Comment: The namespace is there and System.xml.dll is already referenced by the build system. in the link he uses JSON.DeserializeXmlNode, in my case its JsonConvert.DeserializedXNode. There is no XmlNode it's XNode, besides for me (xmldoc.LoadXml(xml.InnerXml)) I have no InnerXml !

Comment: Is your intent to write a general-purpose json - to - csv converter that will work with any data? That will be difficult because json is hierarchical and csv is flat.

Comment: let's suppose that I know the content of my json, is there any way to write to a csv?